# Get Distance in Miles not correct Google Maps Angular?

Tags: angular, maps

I have a method that tries to calculate the disatnce in miles from brighton to london. Google states it's 81.4 miles away, but this method prints 48. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
private calculateDistance(userLong: number, userLat: number): void {
    const london = new google.maps.LatLng(51.509865, -0.118092); //london longlat
    const userLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(50.827778, -0.152778); //brighton longlat
    const distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
      userLocation,
      london
    );

    console.log(Math.ceil(distance * 0.00062137));//logs 48 and not 81.4
  }
```

can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that there're 81.4 miles? "googling" in car by M23 and A23 give me 53 miles (I suppose the distance straight line is less)

Comment: just distance between london and brighton via a google search. I'm using Lat and Long with spherical, so just wanted to see that the figure was similar, but it's way off.